# Threading: networking thread, gui thread, backend thread postoffice intermediary class a good setup?

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, networking, architecture

I tend to use the following as my standard threading model, but maybe it isn't such a great model. What other suggestions do people have or do they think this is set up well? This is not for a high performance internet server, though performance is sometimes pretty critical and in those cases I use asynchronous networking methods and reuse buffers, but it is the same model.

There is a gui thread to run the gui.

There is a backend thread that handles anything that is computationally intensive (basically anything the gui can hand off that isn't pretty quick to run) and also is in charge of parsing and acting on incoming messages or gui actions.

There is one or more networking threads that take care of breaking an outgoing send into peices if necessary, recieving packets from various sockets and reassembling them into messages.

There is an intermediary static class which serves as an intermediary between the networking and backend threads. It acts as a post office. Messages that need to go out are posted to it by backend threads and networking threads check the "outbox" of this class to find messages to send and post any incoming messages in a static "inbox" this class has (regardless of the socket they arrive from, though that information is posted with the incoming message) which the backend thread checks to find messages from other machines it should act on.

The gui / backend threading interface tends to be more ad hoc and should probably have its own post office like class or some alternative intermediary?

Any comments/suggestions on this threading setup?

Answer (score 1):

My primary concern is that you don't really want to lock yourself into the idea that there can only be one back-end thread.  My normal model is to use the MVC at first, make sure all the data structures I use aren't inherently unsafe for a threaded environment, avoid singletons, and then profile like crazy, splitting things out as I go while trying to minimize the number of condition variables I'm leveraging.  For long asynchronous tasks, I prefer to spawn a new process, particularly if it's something that might want to let the OS give it a differing priority.

Answer (score 0):

This architecture sounds like the classic [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) architecture which is usually considered as good.